# cdo remapdis (Abort): proj library support not compiled in

Tags: python, cdo-climate, proj

sea ice drift data: https://nsidc.org/data/nsidc-0116/versions/4
[image]

I try to resample this data into longitudexlatitude=r720x361 grid, so I tried cdo remapdis command:
[image]
and then I check my cdo library, and find there's no proj library here.
[image]
then I try to download proj library and compile in cdo. According to cdo documentation:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
but it report error:
[image]
How can I compile proj library into cdo? Thank you for any answer!

Comment: Based on the question you are working in conda. You should install the conda version of CDO as it will have all of the necessary libraries co-installed for you.